# Vertical aligning image caption and sidebar notes with body text?

Tags: typography, grids

How do you vertical-align smaller type such as image captions or sidenotes with body type? Do you align it with the cap height or the baseline? What are the benefits?

I'm looking for general guidance.

Some book authors prefer to align smaller (and larger) type with the body baseline but some (for example Joseph Muller Brockmann) prefer to align text with the body cap-height.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very interesting subject. I would like to see more typography questions here. But this is a bit low effort imo. I do have some thoughts on this subject, but if I were to answer this it would quickly become like writing a whole chapter for a book. So many different cases, placements, fonts, styles to take into account. Can you perhaps narrow it down a bit? Maybe produce some examples for us to use a a starting point?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE.  I'd also like to see an example showing the problem to be solved.  We like pictures here. It's really hard to answer such questions without seeing something.

Comment: Sure! I'll be back.